# R - How to subset all dataframes stored in a list according to a vector of conditions

Tags: r, dataframe, lapply

This is my first time asking a question here so please let me know if I need to change the way I am doing this. I have been looking for awhile and I haven't been able to find what I need.

I have a list of 3 dataframes. They have the same structure (variables) but not the same number of observations. I would like to get several subsets for each dataframe in my list, according to several conditions stored in a vector.

So if I have 5 conditions, I need to get, for each of the 3 dataframes in my list, 5 subsets of these dataframes, so 15 total.

For instance:

```
df1 <-data.frame(replicate(3,sample(0:10,10,rep=TRUE)))
df2 <-data.frame(replicate(3,sample(0:10,7,rep=TRUE)))
df3 <-data.frame(replicate(3,sample(0:10,8,rep=TRUE)))

my_list <- list(df1, df2, df3)

conditions <- c(2, 5, 7, 4, 6)
```

I know how to subset for one of the conditions using lapply

```
list_subset <- lapply(my_list, function(x) x[which(x$X1 == conditions[1]), ])
```

But I would like to do that for all the values in the vector conditions.
I hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just lapply again, this time over the conditions:

```
df1 <-data.frame(replicate(3,sample(0:10,10,rep=TRUE)))
df2 <-data.frame(replicate(3,sample(0:10,7,rep=TRUE)))
df3 <-data.frame(replicate(3,sample(0:10,8,rep=TRUE)))

my_list <- list(df1, df2, df3)

conditions <- c(2, 5, 7, 4, 6)

list_subset <- lapply(my_list, function(x) x[which(x$X1 == conditions[1]), ])

#One Way, Conditions on first list
list.of.list_subsets <- lapply(conditions,function(y){
  lapply(my_list, function(x) x[which(x$X1 == y), ])
})
#The other way around
list.of.list_subsets2 <- lapply(my_list,function(x){
  lapply(conditions, function(y) x[which(x$X1 == y), ])
})
```

Answer (score 1):

An option would be to filter with `%in%` and then `split` based on the 'X1' column

```
lapply(my_list, function(x) {x1 <- subset(x, X1 %in% conditions); split(x1, x1$X1)})
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip!